# Remove image from PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'd like to remove certain images shown in pages using `PDFBox` library. As far as I know the most appropriate way of identifying an image is to its "name" in `XOBJECT` directory. So theoretically everything what should be done is to remove such an image from `XOBJECT` directory and operators that display that image. This is how I dealt with the problem of removing an image from a page. `Using PDFBox Debugger` I found image's id (`Im3`) and the instructions displaying it on a page:

[image]

My question is how what instructions before and after the instruction that displays the image should I remove (`Do` is used to display image). I decided to remove all from (thus including) `/Gs1 gs` up to `/Im3 Do`. Is this correct approach? Here's my code. It is working correctly, ie. there is no page with unwanted image. I use latest (ie. v3) of PDFBox.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.Operator;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.ContentStreamWriter;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import static org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.OperatorName.DRAW_OBJECT;
import static org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.OperatorName.SET_GRAPHICS_STATE_PARAMS;


public class GraphicRemover {

    private static final COSName X_OBJECT_NAME_TO_REMOVE = COSName.getPDFName("Im3");

    public void remove(final PDDocument document) throws IOException {

        for (final PDPage page : document.getPages()) {

            final PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
            final List<Object> tokens = parser.parse();

            final boolean hasImage = tokens.stream().anyMatch(X_OBJECT_NAME_TO_REMOVE::equals);

            if (!hasImage) {
                continue;
            }

            for (int i = tokens.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (!tokens.get(i).equals(X_OBJECT_NAME_TO_REMOVE)) {
                    continue;
                }

                int indexOfGraphicStartCommand = i - 1;
                while (!Operator.getOperator(SET_GRAPHICS_STATE_PARAMS).equals(tokens.get(indexOfGraphicStartCommand))) {
                    --indexOfGraphicStartCommand;
                }

                int indexOfDisplayGraphicCommand = i;
                while (!Operator.getOperator(DRAW_OBJECT).equals(tokens.get(indexOfDisplayGraphicCommand))) {
                    ++indexOfDisplayGraphicCommand;
                }
                final int indexOfDisplayGraphicArgument = --indexOfGraphicStartCommand;
                tokens.subList(indexOfDisplayGraphicArgument, indexOfDisplayGraphicCommand).clear();
                final PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
                final OutputStream newContentOutput = newContents.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
                final ContentStreamWriter newContentWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(newContentOutput);
                newContentWriter.writeTokens(tokens);
                newContentOutput.close();
                page.setContents(newContents);
                removeWatermarkObject(page);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void removeWatermarkObject(final PDPage page) {
        ((COSDictionary) page.getResources().getCOSObject()
                .getDictionaryObject(COSName.XOBJECT)).removeItem(X_OBJECT_NAME_TO_REMOVE);
        removeEmptyXobjects(page);
    }

    private void removeEmptyXobjects(final PDPage page) {
        final COSDictionary xObjects =
                (COSDictionary) page.getResources().getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.XOBJECT);

        if (xObjects == null || xObjects.size() == 0) {
            page.getResources().getCOSObject().removeItem(COSName.XOBJECT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I decided to remove all from (thus including) `/Gs1 gs` up to `/Im3 Do`."* - if you include the opening `q`, you also have to include the closing `Q`. But it would also be ok to only remove the `/Im3 Do`.

Comment: Depending on your documents, another option might be to replace the image xobject itself with a tiny blank image. This is hackier, of course, but avoids reprocessing the page streams. It would not work when an image is used multiple times in a document and you wish to delete only once instance, though.

Comment: @mkl So the output should be as follows: https://imgur.com/a/YW1EkAZ ? Please feel free to write what you did in an answer. Without your input I would not have know how to solve this puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I decided to remove all from (thus including) `/Gs1 gs` up to `/Im3 Do`. Is this correct approach?

If you include the opening `q`, you also have to include the closing `Q`: they mean save-graphics-state (on a stack) and restore-graphics-state (from that stack), so only removing the opening `q` can have a severe impact on the following content.

Alternatively it would also be ok to only remove the `/Im3 Do`.

In a comment you followed up with:

> So the output should be as follows:
>
> [image: https://imgur.com/a/YW1EkAZ]

That would be a valid option.

But if you really want to remove more than just the `/Im3 Do`, you can also remove the remaining `q /Perceptual ri Q` as that essentially is a NOP.

Comment: Is it safe to also remove from the argument for `gs` command, namely `Gs1` from `ExtGState` dictionary from resources of a page? Is there something more that could be safely removed?

Comment: Well, you have to check first whether that entry is not used elsewhere, in particular in the same content stream but also in all form XObjects and Type 3 fonts without own **Resources** dictionaries used on the same page. If the **Resources** dictionary is indirectly referenced from the page dictionary, it may also be referenced from other pages or XObjects or whatnots. In that case you have to find all such other uses of the resources and check whether the **ExtGState** resource is needed there. In other words, only remove a resource if you are 150% sure it isn't used anywhere in your file.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds as very interesting programming challenge.